# eXist-DB / Query XSL transform: undefined context sequence

Tags: xquery, xslt-2.0, exist-db, xquery-3.0

Environment: eXist-db 4.2.1 , XQuery 3.1, XSLT 2.0

I am attempting to transform an XML document with an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet, triggered by eXist-DB/Query 3.1. I am receiving the following error

```
err:XPDY0002 Undefined context sequence for 'child::{}xinclude-path' 
[at line 271, column 48, source: /db/apps/deheresi/modules/document.xql]
```

This error points to the following XQuery in the document.xqm module, line 217 being `</parameters>),(),xinclude-path=$globalvar:URIdb)`:

```
declare function document:doc-xsl-docview($node as node(), 
        $model as map(*), $currentdoc as xs:string)

{   
  let $currentdocnode := doc(concat($globalvar:URIdb,$currentdoc))

  let $xsltransform := transform:transform(
                        $currentdocnode, 
                        concat($globalvar:URIstyles,
                        "ms609__testxsl-withmodes.xsl"),
                        (<parameters>
                            <param name="paramPersonurl" value="{$globalvar:URLperson}"/>
                            <param name="paramPlaceurl" value="{$globalvar:URLplace}"/>
                            <param name="paramDocurl" value="{$globalvar:URLdoc}"/>
                         </parameters>),(),xinclude-path=$globalvar:URIdb)
return $xsltransform
 };
```

To explain the above variables:

- `$currentdoc` is a document name that I turn into a eXist-DB node as `$currentdocnode`.
- XML documents are kept in `$globalvar:URIdb` = /db/apps/deheresi/data
- XSLT styles are kept in `$globalvar:URIstyles` doc = /db/apps/deheresi/styles

I'm using the [transformation with serialization](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/xsl-transform) for xi:includes:

```
transform:transform($node-tree as node()*, $stylesheet as item(), 
                $parameters as node()?, $attributes as node()?, 
                $serialization-options as xs:string?) as node()?
```

I need to pass the xinclude-path=$globalvar:URIdb in order to tell eXist-DB where to process the `xi:includes` inside my the XML documents.

I should note that the `$globalvar` are strings, not nodes. If I need nodes, I 'convert' them locally at the moment as in `$currentdocnode` above.

Thanks in advance for helping puzzle this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs for `transform:transform`](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/xsl-transform) note that the serialization options should be a string:

```
transform:transform($node-tree as node()*, $stylesheet as item(), 
                $parameters as node()?, $attributes as node()?, 
                $serialization-options as xs:string?) as node()?
```

You need to wrap you parameter in quotes and concatenate with your global variable:

```
concat(`xinclude-path=`, $globalvar:URIdb)
```

Comment: That solved it, but produced a new protocol error posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52897533/exist-db-xquery-xsl-transform-unable-to-set-up-transformer-no-protocol